# Creating an image mask with a linear gradient

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy

I am creating a circular mask in python as follows:

```
import numpy as np
def make_mask(image, radius, center=(0, 0)):
    r, c, d = image.shape
    y, x = np.ogrid[-center[0]:r-center[0], -center[1]:r-center[1]]
    mask = x*x + y*y <= radius*radius
    array = np.zeros((r, c))
    array[mask] = 1
    return array
```

This returns a mask of shape (r, c). What I would like to do is have a weighted mask where the weight is 1 at the center of the image (given by the center parameter) and decreasing linearly towards the edge of the image. So, his should be an added weight calculated between 0 and 1 (0 not included) in the line. I was thinking this should be something like:

```
distance = (center[0] - x)**2 + (center[1] - y)**2
# weigh it inversely to distance from center
mask = (x*x + y*y) * 1.0/distance
```

However, this will result in divide by 0 and the mask would not be between 0 and 1 either.

Comment: From what I can see (on mobile so can't check) this does give you a weighted circular mask but simply not in the interval (0,1]. Can you not just normalise it after?

Comment: Yes, I guess post normalization is fine, of course! I still do not know what to do about the division by zero.

Comment: The distance is only going to equal zero for the pixel at ``center``. You could set this pixel to 1 if you're happy it having the same distance as the neighbouring pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to weight to be *linear*, you need to take the square root of what you have for distance (ie, what you're calling "distance" isn't the distance from the center but the square of that, so you should rename it to something like `R_squared`).  So:

```
R_squared = (center[0] - x)**2 + (center[1] - y)**2  # what you have for distance
r = sqrt(R_squared)
```

Then, since it starts off as `0` where you want it to be `1`, add `1` to it; but now that you've added `1` scale the value so it's `1` where you want the result to be `0`.  Say you want it to be `0` at a distance `L` from then center, then your equation is:

```
weight = 1 - r/L
```

Here this will be `1` where `r==0` and `0` where `r==L`.